# Finishing gaps between drywall panels on ceiling

Tags: drywall

Ran some drywall in a room on the ceiling and some of the joints have a gap about 1/4" wide (either at butts or one place by the wall, which may be closer to 3/8"). The gap at the wall was due to its angle and the  other gaps at the butts were from slightly undercutting.

Is something that is still able to be finished?

Answer (score 2):

Those gaps are completely common and not an issue. Pros deal with far worse on almost any job, especially when another crew did the hanging.

You could pre-fill those gaps by skimming and let that dry (or use setting-type compound for a faster job). It'll shrink some, but it'll make the taping coat shrink a lot less. It's not necessary, though.

The fact is that these joints will be stronger than those with just surface finishes. The joint compound pushes through the gap and creates a shear bridge, locking the ends of the sheets together much more effectively than just a thin layer on the face would.

Comment: A good place to use hot mud, but avoid the super-short working time stuff as a DIY - 90 minutes is plenty fast .vs. drying compound that might take a day or more to dry throughly, and does not have the panic factor that 5 or 20 minute stuff does.

Comment: Looks like there is another gap along another wall I didn’t notice, it’s at an angle so one end measures 1/4” and the other at 1/2”, is 1/2” too much?

Comment: Depends partly on whether it's totally hollow behind. You'll have to try and see how it goes. Shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: It’s to the attic, so you can definitely see some spacing in there

Comment: It’s actually not entirely void, that edge is screwed into a strapping I put around the perimeter of the room. However, strapping is a little bowed so it’s not flush with the wall. So if looking up into the 1/2” gap, I’d say 1/4” is strapping the other is just space.

Comment: @isherwood Ran some drywall in another room and there are several spots between tapered edges that are 1/4-1/2”. This is something beyond my control as the sheets are in the middle of the room, therefore I required tapered edges on both sides. Even with a 1/2” that’s not an issue for a finisher?

Comment: The taper will usually fix whatever you're willing to pay him/her to fix. Everyone has personal limits. You'll have to ask.

Comment: @isherwood guess I was wondering if a 1/2” along a tapered seam is a big gap or not. There is nothing behind it since it goes straight between joists.

Comment: It's perfectly manageable.

Comment: @isherwood here are some [pics](https://imgur.com/a/vTjKATy), still good?

Comment: They belong in your question post. That's manageable, but I'd use a setting-type compound for pre-fill for best strength.